# Error - node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts(138,230) TS1005: ')' expected

Tags: typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Below is the versions i am using
 "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.9"
 "typescript": "~2.6.2"

```
 "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.9",
        "@types/node": "^10.12.5",
        "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
        "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
        "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^3.0.1",
        "jasmine": "^3.3.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
        "karma": "^3.1.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.4",
        "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
        "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
        "karma-webpack": "^3.0.5",
        "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
        "protractor": "^5.4.1",
        "ts-loader": "^3.5.0",
        "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
        "typescript": "~2.6.2"
      },
```

But still i am getting the below error

```
Error: node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(138,47): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(138,90): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(138,104): error TS1005: ']' expected.
node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(138,112): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(138,113): error TS1136: Property assignment expected.
node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(138,121): error TS1005: ')' expected.
node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(138,147): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(138,162): error TS1005: ']' expected.
node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(138,163): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(138,164): error TS1136: Property assignment expected.
node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(138,165): error TS1136: Property assignment expected.
node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(138,179): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(138,183): error TS1005: ':' expected.
node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(138,208): error TS1005: '{' expected.
node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(138,217): error TS1005: ':' expected.
node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(138,222): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(138,227): error TS1005: ':' expected.
node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(138,228): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(138,230): error TS1005: ')' expected.
```

I am not getting how to resolve this.
Can anyone please help me.

Comment: Is [this issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/30310) the same with your problem?

Comment: Yes , correct, i have gone through this page and using the required jasmin and typescript version.Still i am having same error. @vahdet

Comment: If you are using TypeScript 2.8 or newer and are still getting the error, then you probably aren't using the TypeScript version that you think you are.  How are you running the compiler?  Just `tsc` at the command line?  Try `tsc --version`.

Comment: After running tsc --version its showing Version 3.0.3 @MattMcCutchen

Answer (score 24):

If you are still having the issue, in package.json add

"typescript": "^2.9.2"

Run npm install.

It should work.

Comment: "typescript": "~2.6.2" replace 2.6.2 with ^2.9.2

Comment: Worked for me. Great

Answer (score 14):

I have fixed it changing my package versions:

```
"@types/jasmine": "2.8.6",
"@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
```

Founded in this post: 
[Angular 4+ : Sudden @types/jasmine error at runtime (npm start)](http://dailydevfixes.blogspot.com/2018/11/angular-4-sudden-typesjasmine-error-at.html)

Comment: i was seeing errors following updates I had to simply remove the caret caracter (^) from beside my `@types/jasmine` version. docs on what updates are allowed by caret: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004

Comment: Thanks for this. As this allows removing the error without changing the typescript version.

Answer (score 2):

You have just change typescript@2.8.4 and @types/jasmine@2.8.3

Like

1. npm install typescript@2.8.4 --save-dev
2. npm install @types/jasmine@2.8.3 --save-dev

It's working 100%.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try this: install ncu

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
```

Update tsc easily:

```
ncu -u
npm install
```

That's it all, enjoy!.

Answer (score 0):

1. Step 1. You need to remove "~" before 2.8.6 or 2.8.9 in package.json
2. Step 2. Remove the package-lock.json file and node_modules folder
3. Step 3. Run "npm cache clean --force" and "npm install"

Answer (score 0):

If you have reached this page when you are not using Jasmine anywhere in your application, then I would suggest checking your import statements on the top of your ts file. It should have this added on the top:

```
import { ConsoleReporter } from 'jasmine';
```

I saw this accidentally added on the top when I was using console object to log into the browser and the autocomplete feature of VS Code completed it with ConsoleReporter and this import statement was added. Removing this statement fixed my issue.